# What does identify the connection of a TCP segment?

Tags: tcp, connection, network-protocols, tcplistener

I have to design a program that reads all the TCP segments incoming of **the** **same connection**. How can I distinguish which connection a packet belongs to, among many packets that I receive? Is it sufficient to discriminate on the basis of the DESTINATION PORT field in the header?

Answer (score 1):

No. Using just the destination port isn't enough. A TCP connection is defined by a *combination* of the following 4 values:

- Source port
- Source ip address
- Destination port
- Destination ip address